# How to get InputStream from MultipartFormDataInput?

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly, multipartform-data, resteasy

I'm trying to save pdf in wildfly, I'm using RestEasy MultipartFormDataInput provided with wildfly 20.0.1,
but it doesn't work.

This is what I have:

```
public static Response uploadPdfFile(MultipartFormDataInput multipartFormDataInput) {
     
    // local variables
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> multivaluedMap = null;
    String fileName = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String uploadFilePath = null;

    try {
        Map<String, List<InputPart>> map = multipartFormDataInput.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> lstInputPart = map.get("poc");

        for(InputPart inputPart : lstInputPart){

            // get filename to be uploaded
            multivaluedMap = inputPart.getHeaders();
            fileName = getFileName(multivaluedMap);

            if(null != fileName && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)){

                try {
                    // write & upload file to UPLOAD_FILE_SERVER
                    //here I have the error: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: 
                    //application/pdf
                    inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,InputStream.class);                        
                    uploadFilePath = writeToFileServer(inputStream, fileName);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                // close the stream
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        // release resources, if any
    }
    return Response.ok("File uploaded successfully at " + uploadFilePath).build();
}
```

I'm using postman for test, http POST method, in the body I send: form-data - file and selected the file.pdf.

When I sent the request, I have the next RunTimeException when I try:

```
inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class,null);
```

I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: application/pdf and class type org.jboss.resteasy.util.Base64$InputStream
```

At the moment I am saving the file receiving it in Base64, but I think that with MultipartFormDataInput it is the correct way.

This is what I have when debug:

[image]

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Have you tried using a content type of `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/pdf`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this changing the InputStream from `"org.jboss.resteasy.util.Base64.InputStream"`
to "`java.io.InputStream"`